# How can I overlay numbers of RGB of an image on the image itself by using software?

Tags: images, image-processing, color

any available software or libraries to help me do this automatically?

[image]

The result will be like a RGBmap overlaid on the image itself.
I mean to display all the pixels with their own numbers(values) of RGB within the image.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I understand the 0/1 example. But how would that look like for RGB values? Should `255137089` be converted to one pixel or nine pixels? What do you mean by "overlay"? I don't see an overlay in the example. None of the original numbers are visible any more.

Comment: It seems like it will display three numbers of an RGB code when I hover the cursor over a pixel.

Comment: This is essentially the same request as the later [What free photo software offers the function that will show a RGB code of an image instantly when I mouse over a pixel?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/81694/what-free-photo-software-offers-the-function-that-will-show-a-rgb-code-of-an-ima) and you *still* haven't specified a platform, or what your real use-case is - whether this should be a facility within a graphics app [they all have it] or a separate app/plugin.