# What free photo software offers the function that will show a RGB code of an image instantly when I mouse over a pixel?

Tags: images, photography, image-editor

Free photo software offers the function that will show a RGB code of an image instantly when I mouse over a pixel.

Comment: What platform? Mac has a built-in Digital Colour Meter [Applications/Utilities]. Multi-profile-aware + Native, P3, sRGB Adobe & Lab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GIMP has such functionality (also dem 30 characters floor for an answer is strange)

https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-pointer-info-dialog.html

[image]